# Cannot find tweepy module after installing it on Windows

Tags: python, python-import, tweepy

I installed tweepy by first cloning it:

```
git clone git://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
```

Copying `tweepy-2.2-py2.7.egg` into `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`.

Then installing it from the tweepy directory with:

```
python setup.py install
```

The final line of the installation process states:

```
Installed c:\users\linus\appdata\local\enthought\canopy32\user\lib\site-packages\tweepy-2.2-py2.7.egg  
Processing dependencies for tweepy==2.2  
Finished processing dependencies for tweepy==2.2
```

However, I still receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Linus\Documents\GitHub\Toxic\src\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from api.Twitter import Twitter
  File "C:\Users\Linus\Documents\GitHub\Toxic\src\api\Twitter.py", line 1, in <module>
    import time,tweepy,sys,json
ImportError: No module named tweepy
```

Comment: Try copying tweepy-2.2-py2.7.egg in the directory you have into `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`.

Comment: Any reason why you'd rather not use `pip`?

Comment: @jmu303 I copied the .egg file into C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages and reinstalled tweepy. I edited in the additional two lines that appeared after installing. However, I still get the error of no module named tweepy

Comment: @WilliamGaul Neither my GitShell or Windows Command Prompt has pip, but I can try installing that first

Comment: @LinusLiang Did you get any results from using pip?

Comment: @Aaron My problem was a result of multiple versions of python being installed, so I ended up not using pip.